# Unload dll from process

Tags: c++, winapi

Hello I want to unload this dll from the process it is injected to, how can I do this? this is how I inject the dll to process:

this is just me showing how i inject my dll into a process, but how do i UNLOAD / UNINJECT this dll from the process if my inject method is this

```
HANDLE h = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, GetProcessIdByName("csgo.exe"));
if (h)
{
    LPVOID LoadLibAddr = (LPVOID)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");
    //cout << "[!] Initialized Library\n";
    LPVOID dereercomp = VirtualAllocEx(h, NULL, strlen(dllName), MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
    //cout << "[!] Initialized memory allocation\n";
    WriteProcessMemory(h, dereercomp, dllName, strlen(dllName), NULL);
    //cout << "[!] Wrote dll name to memory: " << strlen(dllName) << " byte(s)\n";
    HANDLE asdc = CreateRemoteThread(h, NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)LoadLibAddr, dereercomp, 0, NULL);
    //cout << "[!] Created remote thread: " << asdc << endl;
    //cout << "[!] Waiting for Dll exit...\n";
    WaitForSingleObject(asdc, INFINITE);
    VirtualFreeEx(h, dereercomp, strlen(dllName), MEM_RELEASE);
    //cout << "[!] Freeing memory\n";
    CloseHandle(asdc);
    CloseHandle(h);
    //cout << "[!] Closed all handles\n";
    //cout << "[!] Complete!\n";
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code you show? Can you please elaborate? Also please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: no, this is just me showing how i inject my dll into a process, but how do i UNLOAD / UNINJECT this dll from the process if my inject method is this

Comment: Since you create a new thread (in the `csgo.exe` process) to call `LoadLibraryA` and you discard the result of the call to `LoadLibraryA` you *can't* "unload" the library. To be able to "unload" a library, you must save the result from `LoadLibraryA` and pass it to `CloseHandle`.

Comment: There's another problem with the code you show: The length returned by `strlen` does *not* include the string null-terminator. Passing a non-terminated string to any function expecting a null-terminated string will lead to pain and suffering (and *undefined behavior*).

Comment: @some you mean FreeLibrary not CloseHandle

Comment: so my injection code is wrong if i want it to be able to be unloaded. ok. what do i need to change? @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Ah yes, that's the one I meant.

Comment: @alqqu Besides the use of unterminated strings (which you really should fix!) there's nothing wrong with the injection code per se, but you have no way of calling `FreeLibrary` at all so the library simply can't be unloaded. The only way to solve it is to find a general code-injection bug that allows you to run arbitrary code in the other process.

Answer (score 2):

You’re using `CreateRemoteThread` to launch a thread in your target process that runs “LoadLibraryA”.

I have no idea why commenters didn't like your injection code. Looks OK to me. I think you’re correctly closing that thread, however I recommend adding `GetExitCodeThread` call after `WaitForSingleObject`, this will give you the return code from `LoadLibrary` so you can check for errors. You can't call `FreeLibrary` on that handle because different processes. GetLastError won't work either. But at least you can compare with `nullptr` to detect a fail.

The reason why DLL stays loaded is no one has called `FreeLibrary`.

One pattern here, in DllMain of your DLL, under `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` case, create one more remote thread. This time no need to use `CreateRemoteThread`, just call normal `CreateThread` because that code already runs in the target process. Call `CloseHandle` at once on the returned handle (this won't kill the new thread just release the handle). Now in that second remote thread, do whatever you want to do in the target process, and when finished, call [FreeLibraryAndExitThread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-freelibraryandexitthread) API. This will exit the second remote thread, at the same time unloading your DLL from your target process.

More info: [DllMain entry point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Dlls/dllmain) For DLLs, HINSTANCE is same as HMODULE, just cast the first argument to HMODULE and keep that argument in some variable to pass into `FreeLibraryAndExitThread`.

**Update**: As said by the commenter, ideally you need to allocate, and copy, one extra character. Just replace `strlen(dllName)` with `strlen(dllName)+1` in both cases.

**Update 2**: BTW it's often a good idea to call [DisableThreadLibraryCalls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-disablethreadlibrarycalls) first thing in DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH handler. Especially if you then launch new threads from your `DllMain`.

Comment: Regarding the injection code we "didn't like", it's because it will lead to *undefined behavior* (besides the problem of not being able to call `FreeLibrary`) because of the use of unterminated strings.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Have you read my answer? I’ve explained how to call FreeLibrary in this case. If you don’t know how to do that, why comment or downvote the question?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Technically you’re right about the `'\0'`not practically I think the OP’s code works fine. `kernel32.dll` RAM allocation functions like VirtualAlloc don’t use C runtime heap, they allocate pages in Windows kernel. Pages are always zero-initialized, very important for security, and both allocation and mapping granularity is 4kb because that’s how MMU hardware works.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Checked the docs for VirtualAllocEx, it says following: "The function initializes the memory it allocates to zero" and "the size of the region, in bytes. If the lpAddress parameter is NULL, this value is rounded up to the next page boundary."

Op's code is correct, there's no UB there.

If you'll ask "why the string length can't be same as page size?" the answer is "because MAX_PATH constant".